# Unable to link node to brewdoctor

Tags: installation, npm, homebrew, brew-doctor

I have been trying to link node to brewdoctor and it says it is not symlinked properly due to node/ares.h

I ran it in terminal and got this:

```
brew install node
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/node
0.10.32.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring node-0.10.32.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink include/node/ares.h
 /usr/local/include/node is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link node
==> make install
scripts/doc-build.sh doc/api/npm-bin.md man/man3/npm-bin.3
node cli.js install ronn --no-global
bash: node: command not found
make[1]: *** [node_modules/.bin/ronn] Error 127
make: *** [man/man3/npm-bin.3] Error 2
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32: 1678 files, 19M
```

Then I ran brew postinstall node and got this:

```
brew postinstall node
==> make install
scripts/doc-build.sh doc/api/npm-bin.md man/man3/npm-bin.3
node cli.js install ronn --no-global
bash: node: command not found
make[1]: *** [node_modules/.bin/ronn] Error 127
make: *** [man/man3/npm-bin.3] Error 2
```

Any way to fix this? Thanks!